# Compute $\sum_{p=2}^{+\infty}\frac{p!}{\left(p-1\right)^{p+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was computing an integral $I$ with a parameter $p$ and I found that
$$
I\left(p\right)=\frac{p!}{\left(p-1\right)^{p+1}}
$$

I was wondering if the series $\displaystyle \sum_{p \geq 2}^{ }I_p$ converges, i've found if I did not make mistake that
$$
\frac{I\left(p+1\right)}{I\left(p\right)}\underset{p \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{e}
$$
Hence the sum should be convergent, how can I compute $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}I\left(p\right)$ ?

Comment: Seems hard to compute exactly... but of course I'm not sure

Comment: I agree with you about the ratio test, but I'd be amazed if there is a closed-form formula for the answer.  Or are you talking about an estimate?

Comment: The sum is about 2.516793 based on quick calculations.

Comment: No closed form exists for this, at least in terms of common special functions

Comment: I [edit]ed this question to [remove the display style in the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3135/290189).

Answer (score 4):

If you want we can write it as an integral.
\begin{align}
\sum_{p=2}^{+\infty}\frac{p!}{(p-1)^{p+1}}&=\sum_{p=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(p+1)!}{p^{p+2}}\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^{+\infty}\frac1p\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}\left(\frac t p\right)^{p+1}dt\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sp}s^{p+1}ds\tag{$t=sp$}\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}s\sum_{p=1}^{+\infty}(e^{-s}s)^{p}ds\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{s^2}{e^s-s}ds
\end{align}